# How can I scroll automatically to certain line in C# richTextBox

Tags: c#, scroll, richtextbox

I have a rich textbox that is loaded from a text file.
each time I click a certain button, the yellow bar moves to highlight the next line as illustrated in the picture.

[image]

the problem is, when the textbox size is not enough to show the complete text, I want to make the yellow bar automatically scroll to the first line that is not shown without moving manually the scroll bar.

how can I do this?

Comment: Would be better to show your code as well..

Comment: Pretty unclear how you'd want to scroll the yellow highlight since it is fixed to the selection.  Use the SelectionStart property and the ScrollToCaret() method to force scrolling.